# Can't add a certain team as a GitHub environment protection rule's reviewer

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a team called "team-core" in GitHub.

This team has **Write** access to a certain private repository:

[image: "Team core" has Write access to the repo]

I have an environment "qa" set up for this repository in GitHub.

I want to add a protection rule to that environment, requiring a review from anyone on Team core.

However, despite the fact that "Team core" has write access ([docs say they only need Read access](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#required-reviewers)), they are not showing up in the list of possible reviewers for this rule.

[image: "Team core" does not show up in the list of possible]

4 other teams do show up in this menu (1 with Read, 2 with Write, and 1 with Admin roles for the repo).

How can I make Team core a reviewer for the environment protection rule?

#### Additional findings

This team **can** be added for options in branch protection rules for the same repo that allow you to input a team ("Restrict who can dismiss pull request reviews", "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests", and "Restrict who can push to matching branches").

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was resolved by changing the team from "Secret" to "Visible" or "Closed"

Another possible issue is the account, which used to be limited to GitHub Enterprise only (https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/30156#discussioncomment-3488144), but has since expanded:

> For access to environments, environment secrets, and deployment branches in private or internal repositories, you must use GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, or GitHub Enterprise.